# Read File Name in Windows Batch Programming

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to read the name of a file in windows batch programming. I am trying by using different methods but failed please help.

Scenario has been given below.

I have different files in a folder but the length for filename is same for all files.
E.g.

```
1000342578_30062011.PDF
1000342329_30062011.PDF
```

And I just want to save the part after `_` and before `.PDF` (e.g. `30062011`) part in a variable.

Below are just tries but I am not able to get through.

```
@echo off
echo.Date   : %date%
echo.Year   : %date:~10,4%
dir /s /b C:\Users\zeeshando\Desktop\*.txt
for %%x in (c:\temp\*.xls) do echo %%x 
lfnfor off 
for %%x in (*.*) do echo %%x > filelist.txt 
PAUSE
for %i in (C:\Users\zeeshando\Desktop) do 
    echo %~ni
PAUSE
```

---

**UPDATE**

My current code, based on @Alex K.'s answer:

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (C:\Hi\*.*) do (
    set fn=%%x
    set fn=!fn:~22,8!
    echo !fn!
    call:handler
)
goto:eof

:handler
echo !fn!
copy C:\Hi\*.* E:\!fn!
goto:eof


PAUSE
```

But it is not copying the files. Please check the above code.

Comment: Do you know VBScript?  Its string manip libs are [easy to use](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_ref_functions.asp#string)

Comment: If you want to update your question, please **add** the new information, **do not replace** the entire post's contents completely.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in your for loop using _ and . as delimiters, like this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=_." %%i IN ('DIR /b C:\Users\zeeshando\Desktop\*_*.*') DO ECHO %%i
```

Comment: I am currently using the following code but its output is nothing even there are multiple files in the mentioned dirstory.       @echo off

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=_." %%i IN ('DIR /b D:\bpm\PDF\PDF*_*.*') DO 

 ECHO %%i

PAUSE

Comment: Are you testing with a batch file or just from the command line? If you're running it from the command line directly, use %i instead of %%i.

Comment: Your script is working for me on Windows 7 in a .cmd batch file, what OS are you trying on?

Comment: I am using windows 2003 Server

Comment: I am using a batch file and even I have used PAUSE in the end of the file but still window is vanishing from the screen

Comment: Sounds like your batch file isn't running, open it in Notepad and Save As ANSI encoding. Unicode format will cause problems like that.

Comment: I am using the above code to transfer files to remote server but it always said 1 file(s) copied but it doesnt transfer even 1 file and there are total 7 files in the directory

Comment: 'DIR /b D:\bpm\PDF**.*' won't return anything, did you mean 'DIR /b D:\bpm\PDF*_.*' or 'DIR /b D:\bpm\PDF*.*' perhaps?  And as Alex said, you need to put multiple statements after a DO in parenthesis.

Comment: I meant (C:\Hi\*.*) and  E:\!fn!         i dont know why the box is ommiting the slashes...anyways...kindly help me in above code...

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "destpath=destinationPath"
FOR %%f IN (sourcePath\*.*) DO CALL :process "%%f"
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET srcfile=%1
SET "name=%~n1"
SET "name=%name:*_=%"
COPY %srcfile% "%destpath%\%name%"
```

The `SET "name=%~n1"` line extracts from the full path just the name without extension.

The `SET "name=%name:*_=%"` line deletes the `_` character and everything before it in the value of `name` and stores the result back to `name`.

Ultimately, before executing the `COPY` command, `name` only contains that part of the original filename which is between `_` and the extension.

Comment: I'm a newbie on this, could you please explain me The `SET "destpath=destinationpath"` right syntax? thanks a lot

Comment: @Lale: Hey there. I'm happy to help but I'm not sure what part of the line you have trouble with exactly. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

As they are of a fixed length you can use `:~startpos,len` syntax;

```
set fn=1000342578_30062011.PDF
set fn=%fn:~11,8%
echo %fn%

>30062011
```

In a for loop;

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (*.*) do (
    set fn=%%x
    set fn=!fn:~11,8!
    call:handler
)
goto:eof

:handler
    echo !fn!
goto:eof
```

Comment: I know how to split the string but dont know how to take the string from a filename and then split it ??

Comment: This is working for me but to some extent, is there any method to set the value as global because I need the echo !fn! value after the for () paranthesis??

Comment: After the () its out of the loop so would just contain the last value, you can branch as above

Comment: It is also working for me...now let me proceed further... thanks to all :))))

Comment: ok, got it, let me try, sorry to bother again and again...I am new user :)