# Move Files using loop in Windows Batch Programming

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using below code to transfer files, it is showing on each movement of file that 1 file(s) moved, 1 file(s) moved and so on...but it is not showing at the end that total number of files moved ? it was working for my first code even echo %%i was placed in the same location as placed below...plz help...?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist C:\Hi\*.pdf (goto COPYFILES) else (goto NOFILES)

:COPYFILES
for /f %%i in ('DIR /b C:\Hi\*_*.*') do (
    echo %%i
    set fn=%%i
    set fn=!fn:~11,8!
    move C:\Hi\%%i E:\!fn!\
)
echo complete

:NOFILES
echo There are no files to move
```

Comment: Would using PowerShell instead of cmd batch be an option for you?

Comment: Did you try [a different approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664659/read-file-name-in-windows-batch-programming/6680620#6680620)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `%%i` will only ever contain *part* of the file name, so you try to

```
move C:\Hi\30072011.pdf
```

instead of

```
move c:\hi\1000225013_30072011.pdf
```

Alternative:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist C:\Hi\*.pdf (goto COPYFILES) else (goto NOFILES)

:COPYFILES
for /f %%i in ('DIR /b C:\Hi\*_*.*') do (
    echo %%i
    set fn=%%i
    set fn=!fn:~11,8!
    move C:\Hi\%%i E:\!fn!\
)
echo complete
goto:eof

:NOFILES
echo There are no files to move
```

Comment: Hi Alex, it is not working on my side, no output shown, screen just vanished each time and there is no movement on files.

Comment: Also, I have updated the code which I was using firstly. Previous one was wrongly uploaded.